# Will high wattage LED bulb work with this light fixture?

Tags: lighting, led, light, bulb

I am looking to replace the LED light bulbs in my ceiling downlights with some stronger ones.

Specification of existing lightbulb: LED, GU10, 5W, 240V

Specification of light fixture: KR (KangRong), 250V, 100W, K512GU, 2/250

The attached pictures show the existing light bulb and fixture.

I would like to replace the light bulb with a GU10 LED bulb with around 10W and 950 lumen. Was wondering if switching to such a higher wattage light bulb will be safe. My main worry is risk of fire due to overheating.

Thanks for your advice.

[image: Existing light bulb]

[image: Light bulb holder]

[image: Fixture detail]

[image: Fixture]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part number you supply is just for the socket, it is rated for the heat of a 100w GU10 bulb, the socket can definitely handle 10 watts of heat put out by a 10w bulb.

But nobody can tell from the socket rating what heat limit the trim is or what voltage the supporting wiring is designed to withstand.

Common design of that style of fixture is to be able to handle 35, 50, or 75w incandescent bulb, so it is likely able to handle 10 watts, but more info is needed to be certain. It is possible (but unlikely) that the fixture was designed to operate with a maximum of 5w, but that really seems unimaginable.

Comment: Halogen, not incandescent bulbs, though the general point is still sound.

Comment: @user3757614 Don't halogens emit electromagnetic radiation, making halogens a type of incandescent?

Comment: All lights emit electromagnetic radiation by definition; visible light is on the electromagnetic spectrum. Halogen bulbs are a type of incandescent light that can operate at a higher temperature in a smaller package, thus making them more suitable for small fixtures like this. However, this is Home Improvement, where Halogen and Incandescent mean different things.

Comment: Great, thanks NoSparksPlease and user3757614 for your replies!